Flatten Dynamic Accessed Fields for Kafka Header Message using ksqlDB or Flink-SQL
UPDATE:
I am now using these Streams:
CREATE OR REPLACE
STREAM INPUT_STREAM_MSD_HEADER_DATA(
    header ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value BYTES>> HEADERS
)
WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC='msd.avro',
  VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO'
);

CREATE OR REPLACE
STREAM OUTPUT_STREAM_MSD_HEADER_DATA
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='splunk_observability.json', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', PARTITIONS=1) AS
SELECT
    AS_MAP(transform(header, v=> v->key), transform(header, v=>from_bytes(v->VALUE, 'ascii'))) AS `headers`,
    'Dev'                                  AS `Env` -- Hardcoded environment value, change to 'QA' or 'PROD' as needed
FROM INPUT_STREAM_MSD_HEADER_DATA
EMIT CHANGES;

Now my output looks like this:
{
  "HEADERS": {
    "h1": "v1",
    "h2": "v2",
    "h3": "v3"
  }
}

But i want my output to look like this:
{
  "h1": "v1",
  "h2": "v2",
  "h3": "v3"
}

So I am looking for any kind of Function or Lambda expression to achieve this flattening without accessing the fields with indeces.
I am fine with adding more ksqlDB-Streams or FLink-SQL Statements.
Unfortunately, UDFs are no option as they are not supported.
VERSION 1:
I am using Confluent Cloud Kafka and want more observability. Therefore I want to monitor it using Splunk. I have several Topics and want to extract the Header information from the messages, send them to Topic_HEADERS, using ksqlDB, which holds the Header information then. This Topic_B should then be added to a Splunk_Sink_Connector in order to get it into Splunk. Confluent Cloud Kafka is already up and running, as well as the Topics and the Splunk_Sink_Connector. I also have the data in Splunk, but my problem is that I need to flatten the records.
So this is one example ksql-Streams:
CREATE OR REPLACE
STREAM INPUT_STREAM_MSD_HEADER_DATA(
    header ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value BYTES>> HEADERS
)
WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC='msd.avro',
  VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO'
);

CREATE OR REPLACE
STREAM OUTPUT_STREAM_MSD_HEADER_DATA
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='splunk_observability.json', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', PARTITIONS=1) AS
SELECT
    from_bytes(HEADER[1]->VALUE, 'ascii')         AS `Timestamp`,
    from_bytes(HEADER[2]->VALUE, 'ascii')         AS `serialnumber`,
    from_bytes(HEADER[3]->VALUE, 'ascii')         AS `SerialNumber`,
    from_bytes(HEADER[4]->VALUE, 'ascii')         AS `customerid`,
    'msd.avro'                                    AS `topicName`,
    'DEV'                                         AS `environment` -- Hardcoded environment value, change to 'QA' or 'PROD' as needed
FROM INPUT_STREAM_MSD_HEADER_DATA
EMIT CHANGES;

Note that I want read from different Topics but write to the same Topic. The Fields from the Header are not the same from the different Topics that are read.
And now i got 2 requests:

Make it more dynamic:
If the number of Headers changes i have to change the streams every time as the indices are not right any more.

Use the array like on the “left side” also on the “right side”:
Use something like … AS HEADER[1]→Key like on the left side, but this does not work. Is there any other function/way to do it?


So the perfect solution in pseudo code would look something like this inside the SELECT:
SELECT
for (i=1; 0<header.length;i++){
    from_bytes(HEADER[i]->VALUE, 'ascii') AS HEADER[1]→Key,
}
FROM ...

Are there any functions to get funcitonality like that using ksqlDB or will this be added soon?
At the moment user defined functions UDFs should not be used.
I also had a look at https://support.confluent.io/hc/en-us/articles/14541735851284-How-to-query-record-headers-using-ksqlDB and I am aware that this would help with the problem. But i need the data extracted directly. So my output has to look like:
{

keyname1: “value1”,

keyname2: “value2”,

keyname3: “value3”,

…

}

Also using a Flink Statement to achieve this would be possible.
I already tried a lot of different things but did not achieve the wanted functionality.
As said, something like this would be optimal:
SELECT
for (i=1; 0<header.length;i++){
    from_bytes(HEADER[i]->VALUE, 'ascii') AS HEADER[1]→Key,
}
FROM ...

